# Why my MVC client gets null response from WCF Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with my ASP.Net MVC Application. In Service folder I created my WCF Service like this:

**IService.cs**

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<string> GetUsers();
    }
}
```

**Service.svc**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="HelloWorld.Service" CodeBehind="Service.svc.cs" %>
```

**Service.svc.cs**

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class Service : IService
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public List<string> users = new List<string>();

        public List<string> GetUsers()
        {
            foreach(var item in db.Users.ToList())
            {
                users.Add(item.UserName.ToString());
            }

            return users;
        }
    }
}
```

After that I added Service Reference to my MVC Client and created following action to my controller:

```
// POST: SimpleClient/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            UserService.ServiceClient objUser = new UserService.ServiceClient();

            ViewBag.Users = objUser.GetUsers().ToList(); // null

            return View();
        }
```

But in my Index View I got null value in ViewBag. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: You have users in your database , in trace in services get users

Comment: This looks like it should work. If there was something wrong with the WCF service you'd have a `NullReferenceException` thrown way before it ever gets to the view. Can you set a breakpoint on the return statement in the controller and verify `ViewBag.Users` really is null?

Comment: Well, you assign service results to `ViewBag` and then return an empty `View`.... what would you expect...:O) Try `return View(objUser.GetUsers())`. And BTW create a `Model` class to handle your user data, returning a `List<string>` is just sloppy work.